# Correct way to broadcast a 100x9 to a 100x9x1x1 numpy array for computation in Caffe

Tags: python, numpy, caffe

I am trying to input my own data into a caffe model using the python wrappers. I read the data from HDF5 as a numpy array with dimension 100x9. But for the input to model, I use the following code:

```
input_ = np.zeros((100,9,1,1), dtype=np.float32)
net.forward(**{net.inputs[0]:input_})
```

So basically I need to fill out input_ from a 100x9 array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres how you would convert a 100x9 array to a 100x9x1x1 array:

```
x = np.zeros((100,9))
y = x[:,:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
```